# I can not get MySQL Installed after upgrated my system to 16.04 from 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-16.04

I can not get MySQL Installed after upgrated my system to 16.04 from 14.04

All What I tried to get MySQL to work makes similar error like below:

```
   root@alm:~# sudo dpkg --configure -a
   Setting up mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.29-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
   Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
   Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl      status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
     mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-04-14 11:41:44 EEST; 7ms ago
    Process: 1711 ExecStartPost=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

   Process: 1710 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Process: 1700 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited,   status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1710 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

   Apr 14 11:41:44 alm.i4ware.fi systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Se....
   Apr 14 11:41:44 alm.i4ware.fi systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed....
   Apr 14 11:41:44 alm.i4ware.fi systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result ....
   Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
   dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--configure):
   subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
   dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
   mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.7; however:
   Package mysql-server-5.7 is not configured yet.

   dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
   dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
   Errors were encountered while processing:
   mysql-server-5.7
   mysql-server
```

`systemctl status mysql.service` says:

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: en
   Active: activating (start-post) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-04-14 12:2
  Process: 15717 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 15709 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exi
 Main PID: 15717 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE);         : 15718 (mysql-systemd
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─control
             ├─15718 /bin/bash /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post
             └─15750 sleep 1

Apr 14 12:26:22 alm.i4ware.fi systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time o
Apr 14 12:26:22 alm.i4ware.fi systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Apr 14 12:26:22 alm.i4ware.fi systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Apr 14 12:26:24 alm.i4ware.fi systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, co
...skipping...
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: en
   Active: activating (start-post) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-04-14 12:2
  Process: 15717 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 15709 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exi
 Main PID: 15717 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE);         : 15718 (mysql-systemd
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─control
             ├─15718 /bin/bash /usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post
             └─15750 sleep 1

Apr 14 12:26:22 alm.i4ware.fi systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time o
Apr 14 12:26:22 alm.i4ware.fi systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Apr 14 12:26:22 alm.i4ware.fi systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
Apr 14 12:26:24 alm.i4ware.fi systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, co
```

What to do?

Comment: What does "systemctl status mysql.service" say? Logs?

Comment: Follow the instruction [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760724/16-04-upgrade-broke-mysql-server) seemed to get it going for me.

Comment: Hi I can not run a sudo apt purge mysql-server mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7 because I have not sql dump from my db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If nothing else helps, try to

- Copy your MySQL data files to some safe place (external HDD, whatever)
- Install Ubuntu 14.04 to a temporary virtual machine
- Copy your MySQL data files to this new virtual machine
- Use mysqldump or similar tool to perform a dump of your databases
- Copy the dumps to your upgraded Ubuntu machine
- Import the dumps

Comment: Hi, this my ISP recommendation just now. And I paying some small bill for my ISP next month all about this. Thanks.

Comment: What my ISP coming to do. Just set my VSP to safe-mode and than I can do the backups from my VSP. Then when backups is taken then we reinstall the 14.04 and I do all work to needed to save my server.